# Java Spring Framework jmx managed annotation @ManagedAttribute not showing method in MBeanServerConnection/Jconsole/Visual vm/bean list

Tags: java, spring, spring-annotations, spring-jmx

Ive Added Spring annotation's to my code 
but when connecting via visual vm the method "myExample()" isn't showing in the JMX bean list

My code :

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.ManagedAttribute;
import org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.ManagedResource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;


@Component
@ManagedResource
public class MyClass {

   @Autowired
   private Example exampleService;

   @ManagedAttribute
   public String myExample() {
      return exampleService.getSomething().toString();
   }
}
```

any idea why this is happening ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `@ManagedOperation` instead. `@ManagedAttribute` is for a getter / setter methods only.

Comment: the only difference is that ManagedOperation is for all methods and ManagedAttribute only for getters and setters ?

Comment: See the Javadoc. ManagedOperation can be set in conjunction with ManagedOperationParameters

Answer (score 0):

It sounds weird, but you can fix it by just renaming `myExample` to `getMyExample`.

```
@ManagedAttribute
public String getMyExample() {
    return exampleService.getSomething().toString();
}
```

It will even show up as "MyExample" in e.g. visualVM.